# avoid errors if one of variable undefined all script stop working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, case, undefined

my problem Confined to missing a value of a variables

users can put values of this vars

```
var name = "name";
var age = "age";
var sex = "sex";
var weight = "weight";
```

if one variable is not defined ,it make all script stop what's the best ways to avoid this error have atrying with

```
switch (variable){
default:
//codes
breake;
}
```

or

```
    switch (variable){
    case undefined:    //codes
    breake;
    }
```

or

```
if(typeof variable==='undefined'){
//do that
}
```

need to more Tips and Advice in this cases Especially if we have big code blocks ..please share your experience for intermediate learner

**note** : simply my code for users contains vars with external script.js embeded

Comment: What do you mean by "users can put values of this vars"?

Comment: simply code contains vars with external script.js embeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you do:

```
if (typeof variable === "undefined")
```

But as long as the variable *exists* (e.g., it's been declared), you can do

```
if (variable === undefined)
```

...or the `switch` is fine too. If it's possible your code is running in an environment where the variable may or may not have been *declared*, then you need to use the `typeof` version to avoid getting a  `ReferenceError`.

I could have *sworn* there were cross-window cases where the `undefined` in one window was not `===` to the `undefined` in another window (so the `typeof` would work where the other wouldn't), but I double-checked that a while back, and if it was ever true, it doesn't seem to be true anymore. And of course, that's an edge case.

Comment: Based on your "simply code contains vars with external script.js embeded" comment on the question, I think you're going to want the `typeof` check, since it sounds like the variables may be *undeclared*.

Answer (score 0):

I ha run into this problem several times and I always ask for the variable itself.

```
if(name && age && sex && weight ){
     do something here ...
}
```

You can test this in your browser console. Normally press F12, look for the console, and test.

It is important to notice that the variables must have been declared up in your code, or you might be referencing a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: I think it would be better if javascript could skip or omit statements when variables are undefined rather than cause the entire scope to throw an error. Because otherwise, we have to keep putting in redundant statements like this in our code during development. That, or try...catch blocks on every single line.